# Configuring TimePicker in Ant Design to Display and Select Time in 'HH:mm' Format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd, timepicker

How can I configure the TimePicker component in Ant Design to always display and select the time in the "HH:mm" format, regardless of whether the user enters the time in the formats "HH," "HHmm," or "HH:mm"?

Non remedium adhibere

Answer (score 0):

In Antd TimePicker component, you can configure the format in which the time is displayed and selected by using the format prop

Here's an example of how you might achieve this in React:

```
<Form.Item
  name="name"
  label="Time"
>
  <TimePicker use12Hours format='HH:mm:ss'/>
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: I don't want it to be displayed in 12-hour format or in HH:mm:ss format. I want when the user types, for example, 12 and clicks OK, what is selected is 12:00, or for example, if he clicks 1220, what is selected is 12:20, and finally In the input, show the quantity as 12:20 or HH:mm